How to disallow reconnect after disconnect with socket.io, but allow reconnection from internet loss
I'm using socket.io, node.js, with React client and I'm very confused on the distinction between a reconnection when a user temporarily loses wifi for <10 seconds, vs. a user reconnecting after their connection was fully disconnected.
What I want is:

Allow user to reconnect if their wifi gets disconnected for <10 seconds, they can just reconnect and receive all information they missed during that time
Allow users to switch tabs indefinitely and be idle and stay connected
If users wifi is disconnected for >10 secs, they close the window or navigate away, they can't ever connect to the same socket id

What is happening now:

Users randomly get disconnected if they get idle or switch tabs but when they return, they get kicked out of the room but reconnect to their old socket id
Same as above but for when they disconnect from internet.

const io = new Server(server, { // for work with socket.io
  cors: corsOptions,
  connectionStateRecovery: {
    maxDisconnectionDuration: 2 * 60 * 1000, // 2 mins backup
    skipMiddlewares: true,
  }
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // CONNECTION
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  // DISCONNECT
  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} disconnected because: ${reason}`);

    const byeMsg = {
      msg: `${game.getPlayerById(socket.id, game.getPlayers().length)?.getUsername()} has disconnected`,
      sender: "PLAYER UPDATE",
      time: ""
    };
    io.to(roomCode).emit("receive_msg", byeMsg);
  });


There is a difference between end of stream and ‘connection reset’. You need perhaps to look at the ‘reason`.

Looking at the reason, on timeout when user switches tab, it's transport close. but the reason is also transport close when user manually closes the window so I'm not sure how to distinguish it in code to perform different actions
